# Docker Error "Timed out proxy starting the userland proxy" on Raspberry Pi when using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, proxy, raspberry-pi3

I'm facing an issue with Docker on my Raspberry Pi when running `docker-compose`. Here are the specifics:

- **Operating System**: Raspberry Pi
- **Docker Version**: (specify the version, e.g., 24.0.4)

**Problem Description**:

When I attempt to start my containers using the following command:

```bash
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d
```

I encounter the following error for some of my containers:

```
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint react-app (e449c775871d477b187a6821e7354f93d6a84004c907a98f29f6ce72fedba2fb): Timed out proxy starting the userland proxy
```

Furthermore, when I manually try to start one of the failed containers using `docker start`, I get the same error.

- Checked that the required ports aren't already in use.
- Restarted the Docker service.
- Reset `iptables` rules.
- Checked memory and CPU usage; everything seems in order.
- Checked Docker logs, and the recurring error message is "Timed out proxy starting the userland proxy".

Has anyone encountered this before or has any suggestions on how to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hey.. Did you find a solution? I am stuck in the same issue & unable to proceed

Comment: Hello, to solve the problem I stopped my Docker and reloaded the Docker daemon:
```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```